# local variable undefined outside method

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a method `submitAdd()` that get value from another method `polygonDrawer()`
The issue is that I get `undefined` value at the `submitAdd()` method.
it seems to be a this problem.

## polygonDrawer()

```
polygonDrawer()
{
var i;
var map;
var cords = [];
 google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {

            field.setPath(polygon.getPath().getArray());
            field.setMap(map);

            for (var i = 0; i < field.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
                cords.push(field.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6));
                text += field.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6) + "#";
            }                
            this.pointSTR2=text.slice(0, -1);
         });
}
```

## submitAdd()

```
pointSTR2:any;

submitAdd() {
    console.log("**"+this.pointSTR2); // undefined

}
```

Comment: If you want to use a lexically scoped this, as you seem to here, use `=>` and not `function`. You can also use `.bind(this)`.

Comment: Did you called the polygonDrawer() method before call submitAdd() method in this ?

Comment: thanks works like a charm with arrow :) @AluanHaddad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is related to scope, You can solve this by 2 ways :

---

**1 ) Use fat arrow**

`function (polygon) {` to `(polygon) => {`

Like :

```
polygonDrawer()
{
    ...
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', (polygon) => {
        ....
        this.pointSTR2=text.slice(0, -1);
    });
}
```

---

**2 ) Use `.bind()`:**

```
polygonDrawer()
{
    ...
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon){
        ....
        this.pointSTR2=text.slice(0, -1);
    }).bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the following code that is *async*

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
```

If you want to use a value that is available *after* this function is called you need to chain the call. Ways of doing this:

- Callbacks
- Promises
- Observables

## More

Lookup async programming in JavaScript